# How to import ionic.native.js in Ionic V1/Angular 1.x

Tags: ionic-framework

It's getting hard to see documents or examples now that Ionic 2 is out.

I want to use `ionic.native.js` in the old Ionic V1 project.
Thing is that the installation is with `npm`

`npm install ionic-native --save`

But now I have tons of `npm` modules under `node_modules/` as a dependency. Ionic documentation say:

> If you are using Angular 1.x or plain ES5 JavaScript, you need to add
>   ionic.native.js to your index.html

but they don't give example on "how" to place it in the `index.html` - and that is my question.

Currently my file is located in:

```
> find . -name ionic.native.js
./node_modules/ionic-native/dist/ionic.native.js
```

There's no gulp task for the `node_modules/` dir ... so how do I import it into `index.html` ? or maybe I used the npm command in the wrong place ? ( currently it's in the root dir of the project, where `gulpfile.js` lives )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having the same problem as you.

In the end, what ended up solving it was using:

```
bower install ionic-native --save
```

This adds the files to the lib/ directory, which is accessible from the index page.

Then in the index.html file, add:

```
<script src="lib/ionic-native/ionic.native.js"></script>
```

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `npm` instead of `bower`, you can add a path to desired location when installing the plugin:

```
npm install ionic-native --save --prefix www/lib
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy `ionic.native.js` in `js` folder and add `<script src="js/ionic.native.js"></script>` to your index.html

Comment: but what about all the dependencies, how Ionic will know to get them from node_modules/ dir ?

Comment: If you import the ionic native bundle JS file into your index.html you will
be able to access the plugins via IonicNative variable.

Comment: but `npm install ionic-native` install 20 other npm dependencies, it won't find them

Comment: I moved the entire node_modules/ to the www/lib/ directory, and imported:  <script src="lib/node_modules/ionic-native/dist/ionic.native.js"></script>    even though that importing 'ionic.native' works, I'm not 100% that this is what should be done

Answer (score 0):

I was frustrated by this, too. I eventually just copied the ionic.native.js file into the lib folder, and imported it there like this:

`<script src="lib/ionic.native.js"></script>`

That worked, but I worry that now it'll be a hassle to handle it and it's dependencies.